# EventEmitter in custom dialog component

Tags: angular, material-design-lite, angular2-mdl

I've got a custom dialog component and instead of using a service inside of the dialog component I want to use an event emitter and subscribe to that in the parent component.

Is that something that's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With version 2.0.0 of [angular2-mdl](https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl) it is possible. Here is a working plnkr that demonstrates how this works: http://plnkr.co/edit/MSBlJm2ZKtTvMSgf27Yd?p=preview

You need to create a regular component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-content',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-content.component.html'
})
export class DialogContentComponent {

  @Output() emitter = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() dialog: MdlDialogComponent;

  // or this way: constructor(private dialog: MdlDialogComponent){}

  fireEvent() {
    this.emitter.emit(1);
  }

  closeDialog() {
    this.dialog.close();
  }
}
```

The html looks like following:

```
<p>
  <button 
      mdl-button  
      mdl-button-type="raised" 
      mdl-colored="primary" 
      mdl-ripple
      (click)="fireEvent()">Fire event</button>

  <button 
      mdl-button 
      mdl-button-type="raised" 
      mdl-colored="accent"
      mdl-ripple
      (click)="closeDialog()">Close dialog </button>
</p>
```

As you can see there are two buttons. One fires the number 1 every time the button is clicked. The other button closes the dialog.

Now the interesting part: how to use this. You need to create an embedded `mdl-dialog` with your component as the content:

```
   <button 
      mdl-button 
      mdl-button-type="raised" 
      mdl-colored="primary"
      mdl-ripple
      (click)="testDialog.show()">Open dialog</button>

    Counter: {{counter}}

    <mdl-dialog #testDialog>
      <dialog-content [dialog]="testDialog" (emitter)="onEmitting($event)"></dialog-content>
   </mdl-dialog>
```

The `mdl-dialog` is referenced by the `testDialog` constant and an emitter is registered. If you click the button the dialog will be shown. If you click the "Fire event"-button the event is catched by the outer component and a counter is incremented to demonstrate that it works. Here is a screenshot:

[image: mdl-dialog screenshot]